# PowerApps: OneDrive folder sharing

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, onedrive, powerapps, power-automate

I want to write a PowerApp application where different users are provided with documents if they have attended certain seminars. The documents should be saved in the OneDrive.
I cannot get a connection to the Onedrive and display the documents in a list.
I ask for help

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can only connect to an Excel spreadsheet in OneDrive and use it as a PowerApps DataSource. You'll want to use a Sharepoint Document Library (if you're looking for a low-cost means) or Azure Blob Storage/SQL/Etc (if you're able to use premium features).